# XNA 4.0 : Unwanted texture blending depending on a color of background

Tags: c#, xna

I found an issue of drawing opaque foreground texture on a background. Foreground button texture is blended with background somehow, you can see difference between the top button and the lowest one. The lowest button is a bit lighter then the top button.

[button texture is depended on backgorund color](http://imageupload.org/en/file/220194/buttons.png.html)

I set up graphics in game creation like this:

```
        // Set up graphics
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 480;
        graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = true;

        // antialiasing
        graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

And use everywhere empty parameter list with Color.White parameter for "spriteBatch.Begin();" calls without any blending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors are the same, it just appears that they aren't :)

Here, i copy pasted the bottom part of the image next to the top part:

[image]

It is an optical illusion called [simultaneous brightness contrast](http://www.psych.ndsu.nodak.edu/mccourt/Projects/Brightness/SBC/simultaneous_brightness_contrast.htm).